# Fragment incorrectly recreated while rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a FragmentActivity which shows some fragments by ViewPager. Here's my code snippet,

**MyFragmentActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    fetchDataAsync(this);
}

@Override
private void onDataReceived(List<String> data) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()), data);
}
```

**MyFragmentPagerAdapter**

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private Data data;

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Data data)
        {
            super(fm);
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MyFragment.newInstance(data.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The fragments are created dynamically by FragmentPagerAdapter and depend on data received.

My app crashed when screen rotation happened. With some search, I learned that **"When a config change occurs the old Fragment isn't destroyed - it adds itself back to the activity when it's recreated"**. At that moment the data was null for recreated fragment so it's crashed at onCreateView.

Someone said FragmentStatePagerAdapter should work but not for my case. Another said reusing the fragment instead of recreating new ones, but ViewPager creates them automatically and how can I manage this. I want to permanently destroy the old fragments and not re-add them to activity, what could I do?

**UPDATED**

I removed constructor param from MyFragment, and passed it by setArgument

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("data", data.toString());
f.setArguments(b);
```

Now fragment can restore data while recreating since MyFragment could save state(data) in this way when config changes happened

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the orientation change yourself.

It is covered by developer resources under configuration change, basically, this means adding to your `AndroidManifest` the attribute `configChanges="orientation"`. Then when orientation changes, `Activity.onConfigurationChanged` will be called.

See for example [Activity under Configuration Changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Normally, this manual handle will result in your fragment being laid out, and so its size should change automatically.

---

Another solution, is to keep it like this : i mean, on orientation change, your 
`Activity` is being recreated, and so is your `Fragment`.
So you need to ensure in your fragment that the data are available, eventually loading them if not.

Comment: thanks for the tips. Inspired by 2nd solution finally setRetainInstance did the simple trick. My fragments happened not to be in the back stack, so setRetainInstance worked.

Comment: Please check out my update, I removed setRetainInstance trick, and successfully restore the data

Comment: If what you made solved you problem, please post it as an answer then accept it